# Combine Publisher performs .sink action only once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have a ViewModel with following variable:
`@Published var refreshed: Bool = false`

Then, I use this variable in View on list's refresh like this:

```
List {
    [code...]
}
.refreshable {
    ratingsViewModel.refreshed = true
    ratingsViewModel.onRefresh()
}
```

My `ratingsViewModel` has it's function `onRefresh` which is fired on every view's refresh (as above):

```
func onRefresh() {
        myCurrentRatingsList
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] ratingsList in
                print(self?.refreshed)
            })
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
```

myCurrentRatingsList is publisher created like this:

```
private lazy var myCurrentRatingsList: AnyPublisher<[RatingsListSection: [RatingsListRow]], Never> = {
        myCurrentRatingsRepository.ratingsList
            .share()
            .replaceError(with: [:])
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }()
```

The problem is function `onRefresh` is executed also on `ratingsViewModel` init so `ratingsViewModel.refreshed` value is printed when ViewModel instance is created. When I use refreshable on list by pulling down the screen, nothing is printed (the animation works).
My question: is `.sink` only usable once? If yes, how can I replace it so that I can update value from my publisher many times

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, there's no reference for the sink that you created and so once the function execution is complete, the memory is flushed out and the sink doesn't exist anymore to trigger multiple times.

```
    private var mySink : AnyCancellable? // keep this variable as class member
    func onRefresh() {
        mySink = myCurrentRatingsList
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] ratingsList in
                print(self?.refreshed)
            })
    }
```

Comment: And how to use `mySink` next to print updates of `refreshed` variable value?

Comment: you can assign your variable in sink completion closure.. one easy way to do is use Receive -> CompactMap -> Assign to the variable directly.. if you want to do some processing on data, then sink is your best bet